# Why is the header of this site not fixed?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface

If you go to https://www.stackoverflow.com then you will notice, that the header is fixed and always visible.

Why is this not the case at superuser?

Comment: I believe it is coming soon™

Comment: I believe the timeline is [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/159016) @Burgi

Answer (score 5):

stackoverflow and meta.stackoverflow sometimes have different UI code than the other SE sites. IIRC they run on a separate server too.

The header of this site is not fixed, because _________ (fill in the blank). They're probably in the middle of a UI update and only wanted to test it on stackoverflow.com until it's ready to go for the other sites, but that's just my guess.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is essentially running "updated" Stack Exchange software.

- they have updated profile pages
- they have "[teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)" where groups of users can collaborate as companies or projects
- they have a "[developer jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/developer-jobs)" sub-site
- they have a very different top bar, where the site logo is integrated rather than below it as with other sites

There are many features in use on Stack Overflow that are not relevant to other sites.

The platform is also still under active development and feedback. They may well port UI changes over to other sites as the platform matures, but as they say "if it isn't broken, don't fix it".

We work well at the moment and it only makes sense to update the other sites when there is a clear benefit to do so and it outweighs the potential problems an upgrade might cause.

Comment: One benefit would be that you could instantly see if someone answered or voted. And you can also use the search bar wherever you are on the page.

Comment: I don't doubt that the new UI has benefits, but causing unnecessary churn in the UI on the 40+ other Stack Exchange sites could drive away people because they don't want the "Ask Question" button moving every other day. Wait for the platform to mature and then integrate with other sites. SO is almost exclusively highly technical people who understand the changes happening, other sites are far less technical and changes can harm the user experience. Not everyone likes titlebars that follow you down the page either.

Answer (score 2):

There is a user script [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://github.com/soscripted/sox) that allows the header to be fixed in all sites.

[image]

It has lots of other useful [features](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/wiki/Features) as well.